# What is the proper way to use readYaml in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I saw examples of how to read a YAML file from a scripted Jenkins. I am looking for an example of how to properly read YAML (using readYaml?) in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Answer (score 4):

The documentation:  https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text

In a single line, you can use `readYaml` like this:

```
def yaml = readYaml text: yourYamlContent
```

and you should have a yaml object you can extract data from, such as:

```
env.SOURCE_BRANCH = yaml.source.branch.name
```

Comment: Isn't this a scripted pipeline example? `def yaml = readYaml text: yourYamlContent` gives me a `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 164: Expected a step @ line 164, column 17.`

Comment: @Aristoteles No, you can use this in a declarative pipeline. Make sure it is wrapped properly within the `stages -> stage -> steps` format as any other code block would be.

Comment: The `def` keyword is only allowed in a `script` or a `node` block, e.g.: `script { def yaml = readYaml text: yourYamlContent }`

Comment: Yes, but you can go ahead and open up a `script` block inside `steps` and use it. Since the `script` block essentially allows you to run scripted pipeline code inside a declarative pipeline, you can use the above code in either pipeline.